# JavaScript, HTML, CSS to Class diagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, class-diagram

I been searching around for a tool that can help me generate class diagram for my web development project.

I have one plugin for eclipse but it only works for the JavaScript and does not link the HTML and CSS - http://jsuml.org/.

Found another that does sort of what I want but it requires me to use npm, however, since I didnt use this in my project from start its quite difficult for me to change the structure now - https://www.npmjs.org/package/wavi

I am using visual code to write my code but am happy to move my code to another editor if it gets the job done (as long as its windows) :)

The result I am looking for is something like below:

[image: Diagram generated by wavi]

Please let me know if I have posted this in the wrong section and I be happy to move it.

I found some plugins for visual code but there all seem to be for sequence diagram and none for class diagram.

Comment: You can use d3 or vis js

Comment: could you please provide a link just to make sure I am looking at the right material :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using vis js:

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Node 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Node 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: 'Node 3'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: 'Node 4'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: 'Node 5'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    label: 'Node 6'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    label: 'Node 7'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    label: 'Node 8'
  }
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([{
    from: 1,
    to: 8,
    arrows: 'to',
    dashes: true
  },
  {
    from: 1,
    to: 3,
    arrows: 'to'
  },
  {
    from: 1,
    to: 2,
    arrows: 'to, from'
  },
  {
    from: 2,
    to: 4,
    arrows: 'to, middle'
  },
  {
    from: 2,
    to: 5,
    arrows: 'to, middle, from'
  },
  {
    from: 5,
    to: 6,
    arrows: {
      to: {
        scaleFactor: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    from: 6,
    to: 7,
    arrows: {
      middle: {
        scaleFactor: 0.5
      },
      from: true
    }
  }
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
var options = {};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

```css
#myNetwork {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<div id='mynetwork'></div>
```

More example can be found [here](http://visjs.org/network_examples.html)